# CURL Request with PHP through GraphQL

Tags: php, curl, graphql

I know some PHP but I don't know a thing about GraphQL, so I'm trying to do an CURL HTTP request to Smash.gg with their API, but I keep getting "Invalid authentication token" back even though I keep using it on the GraphQL tester they have [here](https://developer.smash.gg/explorer/) and it works like it's supposed to. If someone could tell me how to get this working, that'd be great. Thanks.

```
<?php

$query = '
query TournamentsByOwner($perPage: Int!, $ownerId: ID!) {
    tournaments(query: {
      perPage: $perPage
      filter: {
        ownerId: $ownerId
      }
    }) {
    nodes {
      id
      name
      slug
    }
  }
}
';
$variables = '
  "ownerId": 161429,
  "perPage": 4
';

$json = json_encode(['query' => $query, 'variables' => $variables]);

$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://api.smash.gg/gql/alpha');
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);    
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'POST');
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $json);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,
     array(
            'User-Agent: PHP Script',
            'Content-Type: application/json;charset=utf-8',
            'Authorization: bearer XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX' 
        )
    ); 

$response = curl_exec($curl);
echo $response;

?>
```